# How to set value not contained in map with RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, rxjs

I am just getting started with Angular 4, and have a project I've been working on that involves displaying data that is retrieved using a REST API.  The data seems to be getting retrieved properly and the form getting populated correctly.

Now, one of the values returned from the API only contains a single character.  I was hoping to override the setter method to expand that single character to a full string.  I understand I could just change the call to return the full string, however the API is supporting by multiple front-ends and I was hoping to keep them consistent.  This plunker should what I am hoping to do (without the REST API involved):  [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/AQO82KE9qWpjLOfXhFVV?p=preview)

When logging in the subscribe function of my project, fullStatus is not included:

```
this.service.get(id).subscribe(p => { 
    this.test = p;
    console.log(this.test);
});
```

When adding the switch statement here, things work as intended, however I was hoping to have this logic be bundled into the Test class instead of the subscribe function.

```
this.service.get(id).subscribe(p => {
    this.test = p;
    switch (this.test.status) {
      case 'A':
        this.test.fullStatus = 'Active';
        break;
      case 'I':
        this.test.fullStatus = 'Inactive';
        break;
      case 'N':
        this.test.fullStatus = 'No Certificate';
        break;
      default:
        this.test.fullStatus = '';
        break;
    }
    console.log(this.test);
  });
```

Is there a better way for me to handle this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you do a `map` of your results after the api call to include this `fullStatus` property?

In your service,

```
// assuming you have to convert the response to json
get(id) {
 return this.http.get(<url-to-get>).map((res) => {
  let test = res.json();
  switch (this.test.status) {
      case 'A':
       test['fullStatus'] = 'Active';
        break;
      case 'I':
       test['fullStatus'] = 'Inactive';
        break;
      case 'N':
       test['fullStatus'] = 'No Certificate';
        break;
      default:
       test['fullStatus'] = '';
        break;
    }

  return test; // returns each response element with the new property 'fullStatus' added based on its 'status'
 });
}
```

Then you can simply subscribe it in your component class. Hope it helps.

Comment: That makes sense and is similar to what I am currently doing in my component class subscribe right now.  I was just hoping to have the logic exist somehow in the data class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a test class like test-model.ts :

```
  export class Test {
      prop1 = ''; // dummy property (you can define these according to your need
      prop2 = '';

      status: string;
      fullStatus?: string; // optional 

      init(responseData: any){
        this.prop1 = responseData.prop1 ; 
        this.prop2 = responseData.prop2 ; 
        this.status = responseData.status;
        switch (responseData.status) {
              case 'A':
                  this.fullStatus = 'Active';
                  break;
              case 'I':
                   this.fullStatus = 'Inactive';
                   break;
              case 'N':
                 this.fullStatus = 'No Certificate';
                   break;
              default:
                 this.fullStatus = '';
                 break;
         }
      }
  }
```

In the component:

```
  import {Test} from './test-model';

  export class TestComponent implements OnInit
  {
      test: Test = new Test();
      constructor(private service: MyService){}

      ngOnInit(){
        this.service.get(id).subscribe(p => {
          this.test.init(p);

          console.log(this.test);
        });
      }
   }
```